# How to send a mail with snap shot of that page attached with it in asp.net using C#

Tags: asp.net, sql, email, c#-4.0

I m working in Auto generation salary slip project.In this after calculating the salary i have to send the snap shot or the print of that page of the salary slip to employee mail_id on button click.

Comment: What is the code you've already written ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307636/sending-mail-with-attachments-programatically-in-asp-net

Comment: that's what i m asking from u all.....

Comment: Have you tried to search internet there are many many tutorial available

Comment: yaa bro i already searched in net ..bt there we have code how to send mail ,,,bt i want to sent mail with the attachment of that page that is salary page,,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending email with attachments from C#, attachments arrive as Part 1.2 in Thunderbird](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825950/sending-email-with-attachments-from-c-attachments-arrive-as-part-1-2-in-thunde)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Sending mail you will use the MailMessage class.
Either you can send your snap shot by using .Attachements property of MailMessage class or you can send it in .Body property.
For further detail please visit;
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx